# play-pac4j with Play 2.5 : @RequiresAuthentication annotation causes stacktrace

Tags: java, authentication, sbt, playframework-2.5

I have currently sproblem with **play-pac4j** library combined with **Play Framework 2.5**.

Annotation :

```
@RequiresAuthentication(clientName = "FacebookClient")
```

in my controller method causes this stacktrace :

`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/libs/F$Function
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.libs.F$Function
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at
```

com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
                at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658

```
)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
```

`

This is fragment from my build.sbt which i use for dependencies :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "2.1.0",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-cas" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-openid" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oauth" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-saml" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oidc" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-gae" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-jwt" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-ldap" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-sql" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-mongo" % "1.8.7",
      "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-stormpath" % "1.8.7")
```

My SecurityModule class :

```
public class SecurityModule extends AbstractModule {
protected void configure() {
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient("KEY", "SECRET_KEY");
    Clients clients = new Clients("http://localhost:9000/callback",facebookClient);
    Config config = new Config(clients);
    config.addAuthorizer("admin",new RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    bind(Config.class).toInstance(config);

}
```

}

Package play.libs.F is available in my project. 
[Eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcXpR.jpg)

I try basicly everything what comes to my mind. Right now i just want to enable simple authentication with facebook for one of my adresses in routes configuration file.
I was following with instruction posted here : https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j.
Any help and tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking on the issues page [here](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/issues/101), pac4j isn't compatile with Play 2.5.  It sounds like there's some missing APIs in 2.5 that pac4j is using.  What you're seeing in your stack trade is Play 2.5's removal of the scala `f.Function`, `f.Function0` classes etc in preference for Java8 `java.util.function.*` types.  There's doco on that [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaMigration25).

In short, either wait for pac4j 2.3.0 to come out, or move back to Play 2.4.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought that could be related with some version mismatch. Is anywhere information when we can expect pac4j 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Not that I can see.  The 2.5 compatibility issue was only raised 23 days ago.  2.2 is currently under development, so I imagine 2.3 doesn't have a date yet.